# QML AppBar with Copy/Cut buttons

Tags: android, qt, qml

A typical android app containing text-fields adds copy/cat buttons to its AppBar for doing this actions.
What is the best-practice way of doing this with QML?

Should I write my own text-field widget that knows the app bar and tells it when to show the copy/cut buttons?
And how does the app bar know on which text-field it should perform the action? Should the text-field somehow register itself as the active text-field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `property TextField activeField : null` put in your root window so it can be resolved from every child element, 
and on every `TextField` you can have a `onActiveFocusChanged: activeField = activeFocus ? thisTextField : null`.

This way whatever text field is currently active will be assigned to `activeField`, so you can use that - `if (activeField) activeField.paste()`, you can set the copy/paste buttons to be enabled only when `activeField != null`.

As for the toolbar - if you use the QML [`ApplicationWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html) it has a built in tool bar you can use directly, otherwise feel free to implement your custom one - it is quite easy.